# while cycle not stopping in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, file, while-loop

My script is designed to get files (and folders, eventually) and then list them with a while iteration.
format should be:

1) file.txt

2) newfile.txt

3) new folder

and it works! but then the while cycle wouldn't stop. given that i'm a newbie in bash can you tell me what am i doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

FILES=(*)
var2="0"

while [ ${FILES[var2] -n } ] ; do

  echo "$var2 ${FILES[var2]}"
  ((var2++))

done
```

Comment: What on earth is `[ ${FILES[var2] -n } ]` supposed to be? Were you trying for `[ -n "${FILES[var2]}" ]`? Are you just trying to loop over all the files in the current directory? Do you need the array?

Comment: Strange thing is: if you try with the 2nd option it doesn't even start counting. 1st one seems to not be in correct format but at the least tryes.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is `[ -n "string to check" ]`:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

FILES=(*)
var2="0"

while [ -n "${FILES[var2]}" ] ; do

  echo "$var2 ${FILES[var2]}"
  ((var2++))

done
```

You can also just do:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
num=0
for file in *
do
  echo "$num) $file"
  (( num++ ))
done
```

If this is the basis for a selection menu, you can instead use a `select` loop which would be much simpler.